# Mapbox GL w/ geojson - multiple icons for single location

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating a web app of publicly accessible water locations throughout our city.  This would include water fountains, water bottle filling stations, pools, etc (we'll call these 'access types').

I've got it all in a database, using PHP to generate the GeoJSON, which works as it should (meaning, I can call it and display information via Mapbox GL).

I'm stuck on how to handle displaying/filtering layers/markers/icons though.  I have followed Mapbox's 'store locator' and 'filter' tutorials, which I've made work at a basic level, but these all seem to operate under the assumption that each location can/should only be of one 'access type', and shows multiples of each address when there is more than one (stacking icons and displaying a huge list of repeated addresses).

Should I be grouping with my db query, creating a sub-array (object) containing different access types (referred to as 'icon' below), or pull everything individually (see below), and sort it w/ javascript/jquery?

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[{
"id":19,"type":"Feature","geometry":{
"type":"Point","coordinates":[-83.053604,42.307877]},
"properties":{"name":"Adie Knox Herman Arena","address":"1551 Wyandotte St W, Windsor, ON N9B 1H6","icon":"Water Fountain"}},{"id":19,"type":"Feature","geometry":{
"type":"Point","coordinates":[-83.053604,42.307877]},
"properties":{"name":"Adie Knox Herman Arena","address":"1551 Wyandotte St W, Windsor, ON N9B 1H6","icon":"Water Bottle Filling Station"}},{"id":65,"type":"Feature","geometry":{
"type":"Point","coordinates":[-82.976415,42.314787]},
"properties":{"name":"Atlas Tube Centre","address":"447 Renaud Line Road, Maidstone, ON N0R 1K0","icon":"Water Fountain"}},{"id":9,"type":"Feature","geometry":{
"type":"Point","coordinates":[-82.757893,42.283526]},
"properties":{"name":"Atlas Tube Centre","address":"447 Renaud Line Road, Maidstone, ON N0R 1K0","icon":"Water Bottle Filling Station"}}]}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to achieve that icons with the same location don't overlap and somewhat spread out around the location?

Comment: I want, by default, all locations with ANY of the 'access types' to appear on the map, with a filterable list of 'access types'.  The icons can just be one kind...I've done a bit of research that shows that multiple icons for the same location doesn't really work.  The issue being that it creates an icon for each 'access type' and stacks them, rather than a single icon no matter how many access types there are.  I will clarify the access type either by the filter, or with information in the popup.